# LSTM equivalent of return_sequence = True in newer version of Keras

Tags: keras, lstm, keras-layer, recurrent-neural-network

I am using tensorflow as backend to keras. In one of the tutorials for LSTM, it says

```
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequence = True, input_shape = Xtrain))
```

Looking at the new LSTM syntax it says

```
keras.layers.LSTM(units, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', 
                  use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', 
                  recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', bias_initializer='zeros', 
                  unit_forget_bias=True, kernel_regularizer=None, 
                  recurrent_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, 
                  activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, 
                  recurrent_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, dropout=0.0, 
                  recurrent_dropout=0.0, implementation=1, return_sequences=False, 
                  return_state=False, go_backwards=False, 
                  stateful=False, unroll=False)
```

Can someone please provide the equivalent of the above code in newer version?

Answer (score 0):

`return_sequence` is a misspelled argument, it should be `return_sequences` (note the trailing *s*). This argument is still there in the latest version and even in [master](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1911).

`input_shape` is also supported as kw argument (synonym:`input_dim`).

So just use

```
LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = Xtrain)
```